# How do I index a merged CSV file from the web

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, indexing, preprocessor

I need help in properly indexing my dataframe from the web. I'm using the pandas module

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bonsalakot00/Test-Server/master/Data_2012.csv')
```

This is one of my codes for accessing my data repository and reading it as a dataframe

```
frames = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]
result = df1.append(frames, sort=False)
print(result)
```

And this is the code where I'm trying to automatically sort my dataframe from [1 to 258], I tried doing `result=pd.concat([df1],[df2],[df3],[df4],[df5],[df6],[df7], axis=1, join='inner').sort_index()` to sort the numbers properly but it ends up doubling each count.
[This is the image of what I'm trying to describe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK9Lp.png)

Comment: fyi you can use the url directly in `pd.read_csv` if using pandas>=0.19.2.

Comment: even if it's not raw data?

Comment: yes, you can pass the url string. for example, `df1 = pd.read_csv(url)`

Comment: ok thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = pd.concat(df1,...,dfn], axis = 0, ignore_index = True, join = 'inner')
```

> ignore_index = True, will sort your combined CSV file from [0 to nth]

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about multiples of each index number, you can simply reset the index.

```
results = pd.concat([df1, ..., dfn], axis=0, join='inner')
results = result.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: The only thing left is to sort it to [1 to 258] do you have any idea how to do it? It keeps on repeating every dataframe